# trouble placing images in articles using css

Tags: html, css

so im learning HTML and CSS and i have a question

im trying to put an image in an article and make it so the text that is also in the article will not write overtop of or get in the way of the image, but everything ive tried so far isnt working properly.

i was using W3Schools.com to learn how to do it.

here is they're isntructions on doing it
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-image_position

and here is an example of what im trying to do http://www.spacenews.com/article/launch-report/37302australian-led-scramjet-test-ends-in-failure

even with the instruction on the website i cant get it to work properly, could they possibly be the wrong instructions?

im using coffeecupfree HTML editor and loading the site up on chrome.

Comment: don't use W3Schools the information there is outdated and may mislead you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with simple HTML:

```
<img align="right" src="http://www.spacenews.com/sites/spacenews.com/files/styles/large/public/images/articles/Scramspace_4x3.jpg?itok=7JbqmW0r">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
```

When you see something on a site and you'd like to learn how they did it, I'd suggest viewing the source or right-clicking the element you're interested in in Chrome and selecting "Inspect Element".

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vg2E5/) example

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you're trying to do, you can also use **`float: right`** in your image. It will make the text surround your image.